# Add Bootstrap Image Gallery to a Rails Application (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I found the gem [bootstrap-addons-rails](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/bootstrap-addons-rails) and wanted to use it for Image Galleries in my Rails Application. I realized that the current version of the gem doesn't work with Bootstrap 3. And I have no idea how I can make it compatible. Has anyone already found a solution for that problem?

Comment: It´s not my problem to integrate Bootstrap 3 in Rails. It works very well. The problem is that I want to use the Bootstrap Image Gallery, which is a part of bootstrap-addons-rails, but the current version of the gem isn´t compatible with Bootstrap 3. Now I wanted to know if anyone has an idea what I have to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a solution to this for quite a long time. I think your best bet is to not use a gem. Instead drop the version of Bootstrap Image Gallery into the assets folder.